# Binary Search Tree with one subtree

Tags: binary-search-tree

I was just wondering,

it it possible to have a binary search tree with no left subtree?

Or does the root must have to children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. It can also contain 1 item (root only) or even 0 items (empty tree or null tree).

In case of simple BST, try to insert 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and so on - you will get tree like:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \ 
      4
       \
        5
         \
          6
           \
            7
             ...
```

In this case, searching operation will require `O(n)` - that's why it is the worst case of binary search tree. Such tree is called `unbalanced tree`.
In order to avoid such situations we have self-balancing binary search trees.